# Why is my NSMutable not being populated correctly when inserting objects from another NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I have a `PFQuery` that gets the current participants of a particular event:

```
PFQuery *getcurrentparticipants = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];

[getcurrentparticipants selectKeys:@[@"Participants"]];
[getcurrentparticipants whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:ObjectID];
[getcurrentparticipants findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        NSMutableArray *newParticipantsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        if([objects[0] valueForKey:@"Participants"] == nil){ // If object retrieved in objects is null. If there are 0 participants

            [newParticipantsArray addObject:PFUser.currentUser.username];
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
            [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.ObjectID
                                         block:^(PFObject *Event, NSError *error) {
                                             Event[@"Participants"] = newParticipantsArray;
                                             [Event incrementKey:@"Vacants" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]];
                                             [Event saveInBackground];
                                         }];

        }else{ // STEP 5

            for(int i=0;i<objects.count;i++) {

                [newParticipantsArray addObject:[[objects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Participants"]];


            }
            [newParticipantsArray addObject:PFUser.currentUser.username];

            NSLog(@"Part to upload %@", newParticipantsArray);

            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
            [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.ObjectID
                                         block:^(PFObject *Event, NSError *error) {
                                             Event[@"Participants"] = newParticipantsArray;
                                             [Event incrementKey:@"Vacants" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]];
                                             [Event saveInBackground];
                                         }];

        }
    } else { 
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

This is how the method works:

1. Create a `PFQuery` object
2. Query the Participants Class for an specific `ObjectId`
3. If no error, then we create a `NSMutable array`
4. If no participants are in Parse then we insert the current user as participant.
5. Else, insert all participants in the mutable array and add `currentuser` at the end of the array.
6. Then upload it again to Parse

**My problem is in step 5:**

When I perform the tasks in the else, the column in Parse looks like this :

> [["Participant 1"],"Participant 2"]

But I would like to have it like this:

> ["Participant 1","Participant 2"]

**What I have tried:**

I tried things like putting the arrays like this. `[newParticipantsArray addObject:[[objects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Participants"]];` and similar combinations, of course without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in fact the value returned for  the "Participants" key is an  array, you can add the objects in it to your mutable array  by doing  the following:

```
NSArray* participants  =  [[objects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Participants"]
[newParticipantsArray addObjectsInArray:participants];
```

This uses the [`addObjectsInArray:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1408963-addobjectsfromarray?language=objc) method of `NSMutableArray` to add the objects from  the old array into the new one.

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to say for sure since I can’t see the structure of your data but are you sure the value held in

```
[[objects objectAtIndex:i]  valueForKey: @“Participants”]
```

Is a single user and not itself an array of users? The plural key “participants” seems to suggest it’s an array of users which would also explain the result you’re getting.